# How do packages know when document class is in draft mode?

Tags: draft

Many (all?) document classes have a `draft` option. Some packages, such as `microtype` and `hyperref`, can detect whether or not the class is in draft mode, and take action accordingly.

How do packages know whether or not the document is in draft mode? I see that the `memoir` class has a `draftdoc` boolean that is set in draft mode, but this does not appear to be standard among other document classes.

For example:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article} % or any other class
\begin{document}
\ifdraftmode % pseudo-code. This I what I seek.
  yes
\else
  no
fi
\end{document}
```

So, what I want to know is, what would I really test, rather than the fictitious `ifdraftmode`?

Comment: There is the `ifdraft` package that provides the macro `\ifdraft{draft mode}{final mode}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I hadn't located that duplicate question, or the `ifdraft` package. Seems pertinent. In my own case, draft mode does more than set an overflow rule, but that's beside the point.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Your `ifdraft` package does what I need, and actually does more than I need, by addressing certain situations.